# What does the number must contain a value that is modulo X mean?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I get the basic concept of modulo: two numbers divided, the modulo is the remainder of the division...

However, looking at a embedded systems manual:

> "all pointer parameters must contain an address value that is modulo
>   8"  - [Link: see page 18](http://www.datasheetarchive.com/dl/Datasheets-IS16/DSA00312603.pdf)

What exactly does that mean?

Simply that it must be a multiple of 8 ?

Does a multiple of 8 mean the same thing as a [Congruence relatio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic#Congruence_relation)n ?

...or given this context of memory addressing, mean something else?

Comment: Please give further context for the quote (it's not a complete (math) senstence).

Comment: That doesn't parse into proper math. Looks like a typo. Perhaps they meant "must be a value that is 0 modulo 8" or something?

Comment: @bill-dubuque: updated

Comment: @zach-stone: hmm..does the edit help or still not a proper statement?

Comment: Do you have a link to the source? That's still not enough context to be 100% sure.

Comment: @bill-dubuque: yes added link above, thank you.

Comment: @P.S. So the question is about some idiosyncratic language used in computer science (that phrase is never used in mathematics). As such, I think you would receive better answers on one of the SE CS sites (esp. since accurately inferring the intended meaning requires reading a hardware specification of some device, which probably interests few MSE readers).

Comment: The phrase "value that is modulo" occurs in only $3$ other places on the web (according to Google).

Comment: @bill-dubuque: did you use advanced search? how did you find that>

Comment: @P.S. I just did a Google search on those (quoted) phrases. That is usually helpful when trying to infer meanings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on web searching, it seems that the phrase is computerese for the fact that addresses must be aligned modulo $8$, i.e. must be multiples of $8$. For example, [here is similar usage](http://books.google.com/books?id=DdbvBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA191&dq="that+is+modulo")

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This means that the number takes a value in the range {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7}

This makes sense as the pointer points towards the message control block of which there are only 8 options which is shown on page 17 of your link.

Comment: given it is in the context of memory addresses, what happens after address 7 - I assume Im not limited to 8 address locations of thousands?

Comment: You are allowed more information in the address than the first pointer.

Comment: I had a look through the paper and you should see that the first pointer points towards the message control block of which there are only 8 options which is therefore why the number must be mod 8

Comment: From the text "The BC message sequence
control involves an instruction list pointer register; an instruction
list which contains multiple 2-word entries; a message
control/status stack, which contains multiple 8-word or 10-word
descriptors; and data blocks for individual messages. "  The first pointer has to be 8 words. I don't understand the problem

Comment: @rowans: right so we will have multiple "BC Instruction List Parameters (Pointers)"....what are valid modulo 8 addresses for each of them, know what I mean?

Comment: valid addresses are numbers from 0 to 7

Comment: @rowans: hmmm....but I can declare up to 32 command and status blocks...yikes.

Answer (score 0):

That means that all the numbers must be elements of $$Z_8 =\{[0],[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7] \}$$

And so if you have $10$, you would get the remainder after $10$ is divided by $8$ which is $2$ and so $10$ is $2$ modulo 8.

$$10 \equiv 2 \pmod{8}$$

You are allowed to have any integer, but that integer you should divide it by $8$ first then take the remainder. You will fall into $Z_8$ eventually.

Notice that any multiple of $8$ is actually $0$ modulo 8.

for example $16 \equiv 0 \pmod{8}$ because $8 \mid 16 -0$ and so on